# The rigorous proof in the commitment based on CRHF

Tags: collision-resistance, commitments, universal-hash, reduction

I'm reading about the lecture of Yevgeniy Dodis. In his [lecture 14](https://piazza.com/class_profile/get_resource/iiauye4zvj2hu/inhhhsyt9x74kl), section 2.3.2, gives a commitment construction based on CRHF, but the proof of hiding is high-level. I want to know the rigorous proof that why even subject to $u(x)=m$, the still leaves distribution of $u$ look almost uniform to the adversary independent of $m$.

Thanks for any help, hint or reference.

[image]

What's more, if we change the construction in the picture. Let $c=(u,h(x),u(x)\oplus m)$, where $u$ is uniformly distributed over $\mathcal{U}$ and the other things are same. Then, we can use the leftover hash lemma to proof hiding. And the binding is still based on CRHF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is the commitment scheme from Halevi and Micali in [Practical and Provably-Secure Commitment
Schemes from Collision-Free Hashing](https://shaih.github.io/pubs/hm96.pdf).

The security analysis is given in section 3.1.

At a high level, they show that: given messages $m_1, m_2$; Define $C(m) = (u ,y)$ being the random variable corresponding to producing a commitment on $m$ (the scheme is randomized); and $y = h(x)$. Furthermore, the statistical distance between $C(m_1)$ and $C(m_2)$ defined as $$\Delta(C; m_1, m2) = \sum_{u,y}|\Pr[C(m_1) = (u,y)] - \Pr[C(m_2) = (u, y)]| \leq 2^k.$$
The argument is a bit technical and well described in the paper. But it boils down to: although $u(x) = m$, the distribution on $u$ with this constraint is statistically close to the distribution induced for a different $m'$. Therefore, reveals very little information on the message.